# Clear a setTimeout with a variable name

Tags: jquery, variables, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have a simple app that uses multiple simultaneous timers to control when certain buttons are displayed.  Clicking the button will hide it, and reset the timer.  Pretty basic.  I, of course cannot leave it at that...

Some of the buttons interfere with the conceptual function of the others. I need to clear some of the timers I set for showing the buttons when other certain buttons are clicked.  I'm having no issue getting my buttons to show and hide with the timers. The issue is clearing the timers before the time is expired.

```
var addMuTrfOrOIATimer;
var timerName;

funcAddTimer("addMuTrfOrOIATimer", '#trafficOrOIA', muTrfOrOIATimer);

$('#muInACall').click(function () {
                muInACall = true;
                $('#muInACall').hide();
                funcAddTimer("addMUNotesTimer", '#muAddNotes', muAddNotesTimer);
                funcAddTimer("addMUStartTransportTimer", '#muStartTransport', muStartTransportTimer);
                if (selfOrDisClear === 1) {
                    funcAddTimer("addMUClearSelfTimer", '#muClearSelf', muSelforDisClearTimer);
                } else {
                    funcAddTimer("addMUDisClearTimer", '#muDisCLearUnit', muSelforDisClearTimer);
                }
                funcClearTimer("addMuTrfOrOIATimer");
            });
```

So there is where all the stuff is called. You can see where I try to clear a timer set outside the function.

```
var funcAddTimer = function (timerName, buttonName, timeToHide) {
    console.log("Starting timer " + timerName);
    timerName = setTimeout(function () {
        $(buttonName).show();
    }, timeToHide);
};
```

and above you can see that I pass in the name I want for the timer as timerName, then below when the function is called I again pass the timer I want to clear as timerName.  In my console the Name is now being passed correctly, but the timer is not being cleared.

```
var funcClearTimer = function (timerName) {
    console.log("About to clear timer " + timerName);
    clearTimeout(timerName);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to store references to your timers. At the moment, in the funcAddTimer function you are overriding the timerName variable and putting your timer in there. This variable is local to that function so nothing outside it will be able to access it. Also you are using the same variable for all timers. You could set up a global variable that is an array and store all timers in that. Or you could storage each buttons timers on the dom element itself. Adding a jsfiddle would help us help you.

Comment: So am I not doing what I thought I was.  I thought I was passing a timer name, like addMUClearSelfTimer, to the funcAddTimer function through the timerName variable.  And then, I thought I could pass the same timer name, addMUClearSelfTimer, to the funcClearTimer through the timerName variable to clear it when needed.

Comment: BTW, though I did not show it above, I do have timerName set as a global variable.  I've found passing the name for the setTimeout probably needs to be a string, but even then, I don't get the result I expect.  I will update the code above to show what I'm doing now.

Comment: You only have one timerName variable. It can only store 1 timer reference. Each time you `timerName = setTimeout(` it overrides the last timer that was stored in timeName so you lose your reference.